# Field Calculator does not notice selection?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, attribute-table, select-by-attribute

I have a problem with the Field Calculator in ArcGIS 10.

I selected specific points of a Shapefile I want to calculate, but FC is always calculating all fields. Unfortunately there is no checkbox in ArcGIS 10 anymore to tell FC to only calculate selected fields.

I discovered that it seems to be a problem with the Attribute Table since values can only be changed manually while being in the "Show selected records" mode. Otherwise my edits won't be even recognized (even actual typed in ones).

I tried both activated Editor and not activated Editor for FC. Just a few minutes ago everything worked out fine, now all Shapefiles can't be calculated according to the selection anymore. :/

Anyone an idea what went wrong?

I'm not aware of having changed any settings.

Restart of ArcMap also doesn't do it.

Comment: I found the opposite to be the case.  I'd inadvertantly left one record selected and couldn't figure out why my field calc operation wasn't running on all fields. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29235/field-calculator-operation-is-not-working

Comment: It seems not to be a selection problem. No matter how many fields are selected (or none) all fields are always being calculated (or better say: filled). Could it be a bug?

Comment: Several times you've mentioned selected fields when I think you must be meaning selected features because the Field Calculator only works on one field at a time.

Comment: ah yes, I'm sorry for this. Of course I mean selected features.

Comment: What service pack are you using?

Comment: Any joins or relationships?

Comment: I'm using Service Pack 2.
There are no relationships or joins, but the Shape Files are geocoded adresses from Excel-files.

Comment: After testing out a couple of things, I think it must be a bug within the MXD file or something. I opened a new project and just loaded my Point Shapes into it. Now it's working as usual. I can edit all individual selections with Field Calculator again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that field calculator does funny things when feature class is outside spatial (!) extent.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar problem at least with ArcMap 10 SP5.

If we join two tables Field Calculator is always calculating the values for **all** features - even if we select only some features.

If we have no tables joined Field Calculator behaves as expected. Only the selected features are updated with new values.

I think this is a serious bug.

Comment: Thank you for this comment! This sounds similar to my problem. How about if you create a new Shape File from your joined tables (if you have spatial reference) and calculate then? I geocoded an Excel table which resulted in a Point Shape File of course, where the Field Calculator problem (still) occurred. Only restart of ArcMap and Import of the Shape Files into a new MXD file does the trick.